# Icons author on Android

Tags: android, icons

I have a commercial APP with multiple icons that has commercial use but needs refer to author. How could I refer author with Android? 
Thanks for all!

Comment: Create "About App" page and write there "This app use BlaBla Icons from BlaBla Author - http://www.BlaBlaAuthorLink.com"...

Comment: I want something diferent but I think it's the only way. Thanks Milos. Could you put your answer to put as correct answer. Thanks.